# SSL certificate error only in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: domains, security-certificate, internet-explorer-9

My SSL certificate works on all modern browsers (IE 9+), but does not work on IE 8.

With modern browsers, the SSL certificate for my domain is used, but IE 8 wants to use the SSL certificate for my PaaS, resulting in a domain mismatch.

[image]

How do I fix this? Is this an issue with my PaaS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being caused by a problem with your server configuration for your SSL:

When I checked the SSL for your domain `funraise.me` using this [SSL Installation Diagnostics Tool](http://www.digicert.com/help/), it indicates the DNS resolves to IP address `107.21.216.112`

When I used this tool to check the SSL for the IP address `107.21.216.112` however, it listed the domain `onmodulus.net` (which redirects to `modulus.io`).

Also, when `https://107.21.216.112` is typed into any browser (not just IE 8), the certificate error states that the certificate is issued to `onmodulus.net`

SSL's require a unique static IP for each domain they're issued to (with the exception of UCC SSL's, which can have more than one IP). Therefore, I would suggest contacting your provider (`modulus.io`) to review your server's SSL configuration.

Comment: i have an a record on their load balance, which is that IP address. let me see what they say.

Comment: do you know why this only affects ie8, at least for me?

Comment: It affected my IE 8 on Win XP too, which lacks SNI support, creating an HTTPS problem when IP's are shared (not dedicated). See this for more: [Understanding Certificate Name Mismatches](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/07/certificate-name-mismatch-warnings-and-server-name-indication.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: It could be that `onmodulus.net` added your domain to their [UCC SSL](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3908/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate?locale=en), which might require reissuing when they add domain names for this problem. See "Background of the problem" here:  [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Answer (score 0):

Normally IE compatibility is implemented via some special comments in your site header e.g.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

If you have a discrepancy between IE8 and newer browsers, it might be worth checking to see if anything like this has crept into your html.

Comment: what does this have to do with ssl?

Comment: I was wondering if there might be some external css or js being included from within a https request. I had something similar where an external reference to a google font (which was accessed via http) was being embedded in one of my sites htmls in a similar way.